# How to know if a Numerical method gives an exact solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the following 2 step numerical method

$y_{n+1}-y_n=\frac{h}{2}(3f_n -f_{n-1})$

I proved that this method is convergent but the problem asked

Show that for any step size h, the method gives exact solutions to the initial value problems $y'=ax+b$, with $y(x_0)=y_0$

($a,b \in \mathbb{R}$) provided that we choose $y(x_1)=y_1$

Well the exact solution is $y=\frac{a}{2}x²+bx+c$.

How to show that the numerical method gives an exact result?

I tried finding $y_2=y(x_0+2h)$ in the numerical and the exact method and they both gave me the same answer

$y_2= \frac{a}{2}x_0²+ bx_0+ 2ahx_0+ 2bh +2ah²+c$

Is this enough?
Or how do I solve such a question?

Comment: If you integrate $x$ you get $\frac12x^2$.

Comment: Given $y`=ax+b$, the exact solution is $y=(1/2)ax²+bx+c$

Comment: Yes my bad But is this the correct way to prove an exact solution?

Comment: If $Y$ is your exact solution and $y_1,\dots,y_n$ are your numerical solution points, you need to check that $Y(x_k)=y_k$.

Comment: I would have imagined that the following would be correct but I guess it is NOT. Limit of this expression as h approaches zero ,$(y_{n+h}-y_{n})/h = f'(n)$. Then $f'(n)=3/2 f_{n} + 1/2 f_{n-1}$. We could then use $f$ to complete both sides, However, it is not correct!

Comment: @NoChance : You missed the minus sign in $(3f_n-f_{n-1})/2$. As $h$ goes to zero, $f_{n-1}$ converges to $f_n$, so the right side also converges to $y'(x_n)=f(x_n,y_n)$ (while $x_n=x_0+nh$ is kept approx. constant).

Comment: Thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this effort is sufficient. If one step is exact in the claimed generality, then every further step is also exact. Depending on the level of sophistication in your course, this may need to be mentioned explicitly to extensively (i.e., induction proof).